# Voltage divider with a Zener diode

Tags: voltage-divider, zener

I am feeding the following circuit 12V.  The Zener is a 5.1V diode.  If I measure the voltage at the circled point (relative to GND) I should see (12*330)/1330 = ~3V.

If I increase input voltage to when the Zener becomes active, at say 30V on the input, would I see 7.4V, 5.1V or ground at the circled portion?

If it is true that I will see ground then I understand why one would put a resistor in front of the Zener to prevent a short circuit.

[image: divider with zener]

Comment: If you feed 30V to your circuit then the zener diode becomes 5.1V, the 330 ohms resistor has 5.1V/330 ohms= 15.5mA and the 1k resistor has (30V - 5.1V)/1k= 24.9mA and the zener has 5.1V at 24.9mA - 15.5mA= 9.4mA. But you never said the zener diode's part number that will say its normal current which might be 100mA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simulation of voltage increasing slowly (over 10ms) from 0V to 40V and the resulting voltage across the diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS2Pkt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

According to the simulation the voltage across the Zener diode will be nominally 5.068V with 30V in. It's a bit less than 5.1V because the 1N4733A 5.1V Zener diode is specified at 49mA and it only has about 9.6mA flowing through it with 30V in.

Here's a close-up of what the Zener voltage does from 20V in (at 5ms) to 40V in (at 10ms)- not as flat as it looks in the first plot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should expect to see 5.1 V at the circled node when the input voltage is high enough.

The 1k resistor is necessary in spite of the fact that you won't see ground at the circled node - the zener clamps its reverse voltage to 5.1 V, so a 12 V, or 30 V, or even 6.1 V input without R1 will lead to massive current flowing through the diode, causing its destruction - this may be evident if you look at its [current-voltage characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode#/media/File:3.4V_Zener_diode_V-A_characteristic.svg).

Answer (score 1):

You would see about 5.1 volts. A zener is not a voltage actuated switch like an SCR, and instead has a linear V/I curve with a "knee" at the rated voltage. It will draw some leakage current up to the reverse breakdown voltage, at which point it will draw current while the voltage remains relatively constant. It will have some series resistance so it will draw additional current with a slope (dI/dV) determined by its series resistance.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, let's assume the 5.1 V Zener diode is a perfect 5.1 V Zener diode and that the resistors are perfect with 0% tolerance.

The Zener voltage will reach 5.1 V when Vinput is 5.1 x 1330/330 = 20.55 V.

Below Vinput = 20.55 V, the potential divider will behave like a potential divider and deliver Vinput/4.03 to the Zener.

Above Vinput = 20.55 V, the Zener will conduct and its voltage will stay at 5.1 V.

In reality, a Zener diode's voltage will vary with the current through it. Its datasheet will show a V/I graph ('curve' but it's not a curve) of this relationship. It'll draw some small leakage current at low voltages, drawing more sharply near its ideal voltage. If Vinput gets too high, the Zener power rating will be exceeded by the high current through the 1K resistor, as will the resistors'. So the real circuit has limitations.